# Jacobian for Newton method for American options by front fixing

Tags: option-pricing, programming, numerical-methods, american-options

In this paper [Penalty and front-fixing methods for the numerical solution of American option problems](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/2412812_Penalty_and_front-fixing_methods_for_the_numerical_solution_of_American_option_problems) a front fixing method based on Newton is described for an American put option is described. I am trying to implement this method. Can someone confirm that the following is the Jacobian matrix $J$.
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccccccc}
 \gamma^n_1 & & &&&&-\beta^n_1-\alpha^n_1(1+\Delta x)+(\gamma^n_1)'p^n_2+(\beta^n_1)'(E-\bar{S}^n)\\
 \alpha^n_2 &\gamma^n_2 & &&&&-\beta^n_2(1+\Delta x)+(\gamma^n_2)'p^n_3+(\beta^n_2)'(E-(1+\Delta x)\bar{S}^n)\\
\beta^n_3 & \alpha^n_3 & \gamma^n_3& &&&(\beta^n_3)'p^n_2+(\gamma^n_3)'p^n_4\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&&&\vdots\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&&\vdots\\
&&& \beta^n_{M-1} & \alpha^n_{M-1} & \gamma^n_{M-1}&(\beta^n_{M-1})'p^n_{M-2}+(\gamma^n_{M-1})'p^n_{M} \\
&&&&\beta^n_{M} &\alpha^n_{M}&(\beta^n_{M})'p^n_{M-1}\\
\end{array} \right)$$